# How i copy keyframe value from node material property to another node material property

Tags: animation, shader-nodes

so i have this 2 material in the same object with Value as input

[image: eye R]

[image: Eye left]

i already input keyframe on the eye R on timeline

[image: timeline]

are there a way to copy the value from keyframe eye R to eye L ?

inserting it manually seems taking so much time and tiring

thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, the timeline is at frame 1, then just copy your keyframes by dragging a box around it and press CTRL-C, then click on your other shader nodetree and press CTRL-V.

[image]

Comment: thanks you so much. it worked.

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

ah i need to select node value below the node group before paste it
[image]